# How to export and import keys in ant?

Tags: ant, import, export, key, keystore

Ant has build-in task "genkey" used to generate some key and put into desired keystore. But what if I need to export some key from certain keystore and import it into another one?

Comment: You're best advised to use the ANT exec task to invoke the OS commands directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is no build-in ant task to perform the operations (very strange). To deal with export and import one should use generic exec task that executes shell command. Something like this should be used for export:

```
<exec executable="keytool" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="-exportcert"/>
    <arg line="-keystore mykeystore.jks"/>
    <arg line="-alias mykey"/>
    <arg line="-storepass OhWowThisIsCoolPassword"/>
    <arg line="-file mykey.cer"/>
</exec>
```

Similar for import.